# Error in read.socrata when using API endpoint and token

Tags: r, socrata, soda

I am testing out RSocrata with some federal data. I followed the [github documentation](https://github.com/Chicago/RSocrata) for using API to read datasets. What I don't understand is why `read.socrata()` works when I use the url, but not when I use the API endpoint provided with the dataset.

Instead I am getting rbind error saying the number of columns do not match when using the API endpoint key.

```
    > token = "MYTOKEN"    
    > df.url <- read.socrata("https://data.medicare.gov/Hospital-Compare/Hospital-General-
    +                    Information/xubh-q36u", app_token = token)
    > nrow(df.url)
    [1] 4818
    > 
    > 
    > df.api <- read.socrata("https://data.medicare.gov/resource/rbry-mqwu.json", app_token = token)
    Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
      numbers of columns of arguments do not match
    > nrow(df.api)
    Error in nrow(df.api) : object 'df.api' not found
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your question will be answered in [this issue in the RSocrata repo](https://github.com/Chicago/RSocrata/issues/105)